# Error on printing html (with internal links and page breaks) to pdf

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, brave

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="#page2">page 2</a>
    <div style="break-after:page"></div>
    <a id="page2" href="#page3">page 3</a>
    <div style="break-after:page"></div>
    <a id="page3" href="#page4">page 4</a>
    <div style="break-after:page"></div>
    <div id="page4"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try the following command on the above HTML file, it can not print the HTML file to pdf file correctly (I end up with a pdf file with an empty page).

```
'/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser' --headless --enable-logging --disable-extensions --print-to-pdf-no-header --disable-popup-blocking --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --disable-checker-imaging --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=main.pdf main.html
```

How can I fix the problem? I don't have chrome on my machine, can anybody test it on chrome to see if this problem is specific to brave or it appears on other browsers as well? If so, how can I fix the problem so that it works on all browsers?

Comment: OK. I change the output file path to an abspath. Then, it works.

Comment: If I remove --enable-logging, it also works. What --enable-logging does? Should I always disable it?